# Resetting filters before adding new ones

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I am working on a homework assignment that requires me to use D3.

I am building an interactive table that users should be able to filter. I have two semi-working versions.

Version One: It works fine on the first search, but subsequent searches will filter the prior results. (For instance, if I first filter by location, then by date, rather than getting a completely new set of results, I get a list that uses both filters. If I enter a new location in my second search, I get no results, as each row has only one location.)

Version Two: Does new search, but applies only one filter at a time (whichever was last).

My original code is posted below.

I tried using `tbody.html("");` to reset the table; that didn't work.

I tried switching the name of my filtered results to tableData2. (That did give me a fresh start for each click of the button but took away my ability to search for multiple criteria.)

I also tried earlier to put all of the filters into the final line defining tableData (here):

```
tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.shape==inputShape)
```

but that didn't work.

```
button.on("click", function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault() 
    //Add date filter
    let dateElement = d3.select("#datetime");
    let inputDate = dateElement.property("value");
    if (inputDate){
    tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.datetime==inputDate)}; //add if filter to avoid nulls
    // Add city filter
    let cityElement = d3.select("#city");
    let inputCity = cityElement.property("value");
    if(inputCity){
    tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.city==inputCity)};
    // Add state filter
    let stateElement = d3.select("#state");
    let inputState = stateElement.property("value");
    if (inputState) {
    tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.state==inputState)};
    // Add country filter
    let countryElement = d3.select("#country");
    let inputCountry = countryElement.property("value");
    if (inputCountry){
    tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.country == inputCountry)};
    // Add shape filter
    let shapeElement = d3.select("#shape");
    let inputShape = shapeElement.property("value");
    if (inputShape){
    tableData = tableData.filter(row => row.shape==inputShape)};
    buildTable(tableData);
});
```

The expected result is that if I run a search on a single element, I would get all results that have a near-match for that element. If I ran a search on two elements, I would get all results that had near-matches for both elements.

The desired result is that I get either a table that can be filtered by only one element at a time (but which will reset each time I click the filter button), or I get a table that will apply multiple filters, but only one at a time (and without being asked to).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your code didn't work is because you are modifying original `tableData` while filtering, and using the modified `tableData` on subsequent filter button clicks.

You can avoid doing that by using a new array `filteredTableData` throughout your function.

`var filteredTableData = tableData;`

Declare above variable at start of your function, and replace `tableData` with `filteredTableData` everywhere in rest of your function.

---

**No need to implement below changes, above fix will work. But you can follow below approach if you want to apply all property filters on each array element at once, or to keep the code more concise.**

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your data.

```
button.on("click", function () {
  d3.event.preventDefault();

  // Construct a filters object.
  var filtersObj = {
    "datetime": d3.select("#datetime").property("value"),
    "city": d3.select("#city").property("value"),
    "state": d3.select("#state").property("value"),
    "country": d3.select("#country").property("value"),
    "shape": d3.select("#shape").property("value")
  };

  // Remove properties which are undefined.
  for (var key in filtersObj) {
    if (!filtersObj[key]) {
      delete filtersObj[key];
    }
  }

  var filters = Object.entries(filtersObj);

  // Filter on properties which are defined.
  const filteredTableData = tableData.filter(item => 
    filters.every(([key, value]) => item[key] == value)
  );

  buildTable(filteredTableData);
}
```

You can also filter without using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
// Filter on properties which are defined.
const filteredTableData = tableData.filter(item => {
  for (var key in filtersObj) {
    if (item[key] != filtersObj[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; 
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var tableData = [
  { "city": "Chicago", "state": "Illinois", "country": "USA" },
  { "city": "Dallas", "state": "Texas", "country": "USA" },
  { "city": "Los Angeles", "state": "California", "country": "USA" },
  { "city": "San Francisco", "state": "California", "country": "USA" }
];

function filterData(inputDate, inputCity, inputState, inputCountry, inputShape) {
  // Construct a filters object.
  var filtersObj = {
    "datetime": inputDate,
    "city": inputCity,
    "state": inputState,
    "country": inputCountry,
    "shape": inputShape
  };

  // Remove properties which are undefined.
  for (var key in filtersObj) {
    if (!filtersObj[key]) {
      delete filtersObj[key];
    }
  }

  var filters = Object.entries(filtersObj);

  // Filter on properties which are defined.
  const filteredTableData = tableData.filter(item => 
    filters.every(([key, value]) => item[key] == value)
  );

  console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredTableData));

}

filterData(null, "Chicago", null, null, null);
filterData(null, null, "California", null, null);
filterData(null, null, "Texas", "USA", null);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very kindly for your help. (I've read your answers before on other questions; advice is always excellent! I'm so glad that you responded to my question!)

Comment: You're welcome @JuliaSweet. I'm glad you found my answers helpful.